# How to connect from node.js webserver to a DB server

Tags: javascript, database, node.js

I want to connect a node.js-webserver to a postgresql-databaseserver. Does anybody have some tips or tutorials for me? I did not find something

Answer (score 2):

Use a module, google's first hit is https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres which seems very popular.